# How to store the data using ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, struts2, thread-local

I am working with Strust2 and Hibernate. I have to find out the currency exchange rate(USD to INR). I need to use this information in more than one place. For this purpose, i am using **ThreadLocal** for this purpose.

```
public class GetExchangeRate{
private ThreadLocal<Double> threadLocalRate = new ThreadLocal<Double>();
public double getCurrencyRate(UserDet userDet){
    LOG.info("Thread id is ---------------->"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    Double currencyRate = (Double) threadLocalRate.get();
    if(currencyRate == null){
        LOG.info("Object does not exist");
     ---//my code which is used to find USD --> INR exchange rate
   threadLocalRate.set(currencyRate);    
}
return currencyRate ;
}
}
```

I need to call the above method from **four** different methods. When i call the above method, from different methods, the above total code is getting execute. 
My requirement is only **one time** the total method has to get execute. And remaining **three times** the total method should not get execute. The value which is stored in ThreadLocal object should be returned.

Here is my log report, which shows the above total method is executed.

```
[ INFO] 2012-09-20 10:20:04,611 [CommonFormats] (CommonFormats.java:getCurrencyRate:159)
Thread id is ---------------------------->54
 [ INFO] 2012-09-20 10:20:04,611 [CommonFormats] (CommonFormats.java:getCurrencyRate:163)
Object does not exist

[ INFO] 2012-09-20 10:20:49,529 [CommonFormats] (CommonFormats.java:getCurrencyRate:159)
Thread id is ---------------------------->54
 [ INFO] 2012-09-20 10:20:49,529 [CommonFormats] (CommonFormats.java:getCurrencyRate:163)
Object does not exist
```

please suggest what wrong am i doing. The above method will be called from **four** methods. **Two methods** belongs to Action class, and **Two** methods belongs to Service layer class.

My sample code

```
 //Action class
    public class StrutsAction1{
public String method1(){  
       // my code
    CommonFormats commonFormats= new CommonFormats(); 
    System.out.println(commonFormats.getCurrencyRate());
       // my code
}
public String method2(){  
       // my code
    CommonFormats commonFormats= new CommonFormats(); 
    System.out.println(commonFormats.getCurrencyRate());
       // my code
}  }

//Business class
public class BussinessLogic{
 public String method1(){  

       // my code
    CommonFormats commonFormats= new CommonFormats(); 
    System.out.println(commonFormats.getCurrencyRate());
       // my code

}
public String method2(){  

       // my code
    CommonFormats commonFormats= new CommonFormats(); 
    System.out.println(commonFormats.getCurrencyRate());
       // my code
}  }
```

Comment: In the above 611 and 529 indicates the line number from where the above is called(caller line number).

Comment: Your requirements are not clear.

Comment: @DaveNewton I need threadLocalRate variable more than one method(nearly in 4 methods). It will have the exchange rate(USD -> INR). The code which is used to find out the exchange rate should get execute only one time. Remaining 3 time it should not get .execute. So i used ThreadLocale concept here. But its not working. I updated the question.

Comment: Well, you certainly don't need it in the action, because actions are created per-request. Why wouldn't you just pass it to the other methods?

Comment: @DaveNewton Its maintenance project. The code has been written already. I cant change the flow. If i change so much code has to be modified. I need to access the variable in all four methods, and the logic which is used to find the exchange rate should be executed only one time out of four times.

Comment: @DaveNewton I embarrassed to say that , i haven't made the variable as static and final. After making the variable static and final, it works fine.

Comment: That seems quite risky if it's based on user details, implying the value could be different per-user.

Comment: @DaveNewton I faced this problem just now. Can u please suggest me the better way to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think ThreadLocal is not appropriate here. I've never used Struts 2, only struts 1, but as far as I know this is a web framework built on top of servelts. These are running inside web container and its up to web container to decide when should the thread be opened and you as a developer should interfere in this decision.

Now thread local only provides a map of key-value so that its possible to maintain different values for the same key in different thread.

For example, if you have two thread A and B and want to maintain key-value pair

- "name" -> 'John' for thread A and
- "name" -> 'Fred' for thread B

you can do so with thread local.

What you're really looking for is a kind of application context - a place to store your data shared by all the threads in the container. Another possibility is a Singleton here.

How technically this can be implemented?

You might be interested in reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980454/struts2-static-data-storage-access) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730547/struts-2-where-should-i-set-global-application-variables)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Does the below code help you? I have read an article on a website and modified the code to make it compilation free in JDK7.0. The resource I used is

http://javapapers.com/core-java/threadlocal/

```
package com.javapapers;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ThreadLocalExample {
  private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {

    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
      return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
    }
  };

  public String formatIt(Date date) {
    return formatter.get().format(date);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      ThreadLocalExample example = new ThreadLocalExample();
      System.out.println(example.formatIt(new Date()));
  }
}
```

Here ThreadLocal is used as a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made the variable as static and final.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Double> threadLocalRate = new ThreadLocal<Double>();
```

Now the thread locale concept is working.